# Implementation of concurrent blocking queue for producer-consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've implemented `concurrent_blocking_queue`  for *multiple-producers* and *single consumer*.

I intend it to block the producers as well, when the queue is full, which is why I set the capacity of the queue in the constructor. I've provided my own implementation of `critical_section`, `scoped_lock` and `condition_variable`, using msdn primitives.

Please review it. I want to know if there is any potential deadlocks.

```
template<typename T>
class concurrent_blocking_queue : public noncopyable
{
    std::queue<T> m_internal_queue;
    mutable critical_section m_critical_section;
    condition_variable m_queue_full;
    condition_variable m_queue_empty;
    const size_t m_capacity;
public:
    concurrent_blocking_queue(size_t capacity) 
        : m_capacity(capacity), m_critical_section()
    {
    }
    void put(T const & input)
    {
        framework::scoped_lock lock(m_critical_section); //lock
        m_queue_full.wait(lock, [&]{ return !full(); });
        m_internal_queue.push(input);
        m_queue_empty.notify_all();
    }
    T take()
    {
        framework::scoped_lock lock(m_critical_section); //lock
        m_queue_empty.wait(lock, [&]{ return !empty(); });
        T output = m_internal_queue.front();
        m_internal_queue.pop();
        m_queue_full.notify_all();
        return output;
    }
    bool full() const
    {
        framework::scoped_lock lock(m_critical_section);
        if ( m_internal_queue.size() > m_capacity )
        {
            throw std::logic_error("size of concurrent_blocking_queue cannot be greater than the capacity.");
        }
        return m_internal_queue.size() == m_capacity;
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
        framework::scoped_lock lock(m_critical_section);
        return m_internal_queue.empty();
    }
    //..
};
```

And the remaining classes are posted below. Note that I've implemented them in `.h` and `.cpp` files, but here I've merged them to make the post short and simple, and have removed the namespace for brevity, otherwise all classes are defined in `framework` namespace.

- critical_section derives *publicly* from [CRITICAL_SECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

  ```
  class critical_section : public CRITICAL_SECTION, public noncopyable
  {
   public:
      critical_section(void) { ::InitializeCriticalSection(this); }
      ~critical_section(void) { ::DeleteCriticalSection(this); }
      void lock() { ::EnterCriticalSection(this); }
      void unlock() { ::LeaveCriticalSection(this); }
  };
  ```
- condition_variable derives *privately* from [CONDITION_VARIABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

  ```
  class condition_variable : private CONDITION_VARIABLE, public noncopyable
  {
   public:
      condition_variable() { ::InitializeConditionVariable(this); }
      ~condition_variable(void) {}
      void wait(scoped_lock & lock)
      {
         if (!::SleepConditionVariableCS (this, &lock.m_cs, INFINITE))
         {
            DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
            std::string msg = format("SleepConditionVariableCS() failed with error code = 0x%X.", error);
            throw std::runtime_error(msg);
         }
      }
      void wait(scoped_lock & lock, std::function<bool()> predicate)
      {
         while( !predicate() )  {  wait(lock);  }
      }
      void notify_one() { ::WakeConditionVariable(this); }
      void notify_all() { ::WakeAllConditionVariable(this); }
  };
  ```
- scoped_lock

  ```
  class scoped_lock : public noncopyable
  {
     friend class condition_variable;
     critical_section & m_cs;
   public:
     scoped_lock(critical_section & cs) : m_cs(cs) { m_cs.lock(); }
     ~scoped_lock(void) { m_cs.unlock(); }
  };
  ```

Comment: Does the implementation you use for condition variables unlock the mutex lock in the call to wait() like it does in Posix? If not, then Ive located a dead-lock.

Comment: @Brady: As the MSDN doc says [Sleeps on the specified condition variable and releases the specified critical section as an atomic operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686301(v=vs.85).aspx), so yes, the condition variable unlocks the mutex in `wait()`.

Comment: ok, thanks. I wasnt sure about the MS implementation. Another question as you can see in my answer: are the locks recursive? If not, then there is a dead-lock.

Comment: @Brady: Yes, we can recursively lock `CRITICAL_SECTION` as per the MSDN.

Comment: One last comment, it seems odd that the threads should call `m_queue_empty.notify_all()` if no other threads are waiting. If that behavior is allowed/supported by MSDN, then the rest looks ok to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Basic comments:

No point in functions that do nothing.
Also avoid `void` as definition for empty parameter list.

```
~condition_variable(void) {}
```

Why put a member that has no default constructor in the initializer list ( I can go either way)

```
concurrent_blocking_queue(size_t capacity) 
    : m_capacity(capacity), m_critical_section()
```

**But** you should be consistent and thus if you do it for one then you should do it for all members.

#### Design:

When you call `full()` and `empty()` from within other members you already have a lock. Yet you are calling a function that will add another level of locking. And locking is usually relatively expensive.

```
    m_queue_full.wait(lock, [&]{ return !full(); });

    m_queue_empty.wait(lock, [&]{ return !empty(); });
```

Thus I would change the above to call a private version of these function that do not use locks.

```
    // OLD STUFF
    m_queue_full.wait(lock, [&]{ return !test_full(); });

    // OLD STUFF
    m_queue_empty.wait(lock, [&]{ return !test_empty(); });

    bool full() const
    {
      framework::scoped_lock lock(m_critical_section);
      return test_full();
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
      framework::scoped_lock lock(m_critical_section);
      return test_empty();
    }

    private:
    bool test_full()  const {STUFF}
    bool test_empty() const {STUFF}
```

Comment: 1) The destructor was generated by MSVS itself. I'm just too lazy to remove it from my code. 2) thanks for the idea of `test_full()` and `test_empty()`. They're good improvements to my code. 3) I assume there is no dead-lock in the implementation of the queue, as everyone here seems to have this opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
T take()
```

I do not like `take()` function returning by value. What if `T`'s copy constructor throws an exception? This was the exact reason for having separate `front()` and `pop()` functions in `std::stack`.

In my implementation of a similar queue I took a different approach: the queue never removes its last element** and the `take()` function returns by (const) reference. This works and is easy to implement if the queue is designed for only one consumer, which was my case.

** Well, it does on queue destruction.

Comment: Won't the copy be elided (assuming C++11)?

Comment: @svick: Not entirely: one copy has to be made since the original object (the one in queue) is destroyed (m_internal_queue.pop();). A copy from return output; can and probably be elided.